# Spark : java ClassNotFoundException

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Spark is giving me ClassNotFoundException when i am using a simple foreach and iterating over a dataframe.I am confused as it is returning the input dataframe correctly.But i am not able to iterate over it.What might be the issue?

My code :

```
import scala.collection.Iterable
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import scala.collection.mutable._

object Script {
  def execute(spark: SparkSession,
              input: Iterable[Dataset[Row]]): Dataset[Row] = {
        import spark.implicits._
        val input=spark.table("input")
        input.foreach(r => println(r))
        input
  }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: $line14.$read$$iw$$iw$Script$2$$anonfun$execute$1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1925)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2099)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2126)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1625)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:465)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please post your Spark and Scala versions

Comment: scalaVersion=2.11, spark Version : 3.0.1

Comment: actually now for some strange reason it is working if I use input.collect.foreach(r => println(r))